# Hazard SEALS Europa League final spot

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, british-english

> Chelsea 1-1 Frankfurt: Hazard **seals** Europa League final spot after Kepa penalty heroics

The title is confusing. How can one seal the spot in a competition? What does *to seal* mean here? Is it *to cover*, or *to close*, or *to mark*? Any of its meanings doesn't seem to fit well. I googled for football expressions with *seal* but found only *seal dribble*, which is a different story.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [seal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seal) meaning "**to confirm or make secure**" like in the idiom "[seal the deal](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/seal+the+deal)."

It means that their performance in the game has ***confirmed*** or ***secured*** or ***guaranteed*** their spot in the finals.

Comment: Thank you for the idiom, now it makes sense